# Python Ursina: Mi clase no responde

Tags: python

Estoy participando en una jam en la que hay que hacer tu juego en un editor de código web (Replit) y entonces, empece hoy a programar el juego. El juego va a ser de una serpiente, así que hice una clase llamada `Snake()` que instanciara la serpiente, hice una variable `player = Snake()` y esta es la clase:

```
from ursina import *;
import random;

app = Ursina();

class Snake(Entity):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(
        parent = scene,
        model = 'circle',
        color = color.green,
        texture = 'white_cube',
        collider = "box"
    )

app.run();
```

(este extracto de codigo esta resumido)

Hay mas clases, como por ejemplo la de la comida (manzana):

```
class Apple(Entity):
def __init__(self, position):
    super().__init__(
        parent = scene,
        model = 'circle',
        color = color.red,
        position = position,
        scale = (0.5, 0.5),
        collider = "box"
    )
```

Que no entiendo porque, funciona perfectamente, ya que luego hago una variable `apple = Apple()` y se instancia y funciona bien, solo esta clase no funciona por alguna razon

¿Por que no funciona? Pyflakes dice que el error esta en que "Entity no esta definido, o importa ursina" Pero esta importada, esta importada con el * para importar todo

Gracias de antemano.

PD: Dejo todo el codigo:

```
from ursina import *
import random;

app = Ursina()

global direction
direction = "iz";

window.borderless = False

def update():
    global direction;
    global apple;
    global hamburger;
    if (held_keys['a']):
        direction = "de";
    if (held_keys['d']):
        direction = "iz";
    if (held_keys['w']):
        direction = "ar";
    if (held_keys['s']):
        direction = "ab";

    if (direction == "ar"):
        player.y += 5 * time.dt;
    if (direction == "ab"):
        player.y -= 5 * time.dt;
    if (direction == "iz"):
        player.x += 5 * time.dt;
    if (direction == "de"):
        player.x -= 5 * time.dt;

    hit_info = player.intersects();
    if (hit_info.hit):
        if (hit_info.entity in apples):
            destroy(apple)
            player.scale -= 0.1
            apple = Apple((random.random(), random.random()));
            apples.append(apple);
        elif (hit_info.entity in hamburgers):
            destroy(hamburger)
            player.scale += (0.1, 0.1)
            hamburger = Hamburger((random.randint(0, 3), random.randint(0, 3)));
            hamburgers.append(hamburger);
    print("X:",player.x);
    print("Y:",player.y);
    print("SCALE:", player.scale);


class Snake(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            parent = scene,
            model = 'circle',
            color = color.green,
            texture = 'white_cube',
            collider = "box"
        )

class Apple(Entity):
    def __init__(self, position):
        super().__init__(
            parent = scene,
            model = 'circle',
            color = color.red,
            position = position,
            scale = (0.5, 0.5),
            collider = "box"
        )

class Hamburger(Entity):
    def __init__(self, position):
        super().__init__(
            parent = scene,
            model = 'circle',
            color = color.brown,
            position = position,
            scale = (0.6, 0.6),
            collider = 'box'
        )

hamburgers = [];
apples = [];
hamburger = Hamburger((random.randint(0, 3), random.randint(0, 3)));
hamburgers.append(hamburger);
player = Snake();
apple = Apple((random.random(), random.random()));
apples.append(apple);

app.run()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Solucion**

No habia puesto en la clase el argumento `position = (x, y)` para que se instancie la serpiente, aunque igual es extraño porque en el VS Code lo he probado y funciona excelente

Answer (score 0):

A lo mejor es el editor, replit no es muy bueno con las apps graficas.
Hice una plantilla en Replit para Ursina, aqui la tienes

https://replit.com/@aslanpelfalso/Ursina?v=1#main.py

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).